# Combining Threading with the "with" Keyword

Tags: python, multithreading, with-statement

When I run the following program:

```
import threading
class foo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Enter"
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print "Exit"

    def run():
        print "run"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with foo() as f:
        f.start()
```

I get this as the output

```
C:\>python test2.py
Enter
Exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 17, in <module>
    f.start()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Is there any way to combine the with keyword's guaranteed cleanup code execution with a threaded class?

Answer (score 4):

```
import threading
class foo(threading.Thread):
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Enter"
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.join() # wait for thread finished
        print "Exit"
    def run(self):
        print "run"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with foo() as f:
        f.start()
```

Your `__enter__` method should `return self`; that's what gets assigned to the variable in the `with ... as f` construct.

Having the thread join in `__exit__` as [suggested by @linjunhalida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188642/344821) is also a good idea, but not causing your current problem.

You should also change the definition of `run` to `def run(self)` if you want it to be usable. :)

Answer (score -3):

Simply wait thread finish execution by using join: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

```
import threading
class foo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Enter"
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.thread.join() # wait for thread finished
        print "Exit"

    def run():
        print "run"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with foo() as f:
        f.start()
```